# disable incoming calls

Tags: android

is it possibe to disable incoming calls.

Comment: I am just starting to learn the android API, so I do not know the answer to your question but I hope that if you can, that you make it pretty clear someplace in the UI that the incoming calls are disabled.  you would have some pretty pissed users of they were not able to receive calls and they did not know why.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd ever want to do this from a normal android app...

Answer (score 3):

wow mate, your question is amazingly detailed, I almost feel like my answer should only say:

**Yes**

Luckily for you I'm in a good mood so I'll explain..

Basically, as far as I know it is not possible from typical android application.

Workaround is to enable *airplane mode*. It will disable all communication so as long as app is running no calls would get through. Also depends whether or not you need other networks running (Wifi etc).

But to be honest.. why would you want to do that? It should be users choice if they want to answer incoming call or not.

Comment: Why would I want to do that .. Company reps on the road are required by internal company policy to turn off phones when driving so as not to be distracted by incoming calls. We would like to track the reps using gps hence the need to disable calls. Airplane mode is not suitable as all communication would be disabled.  I understand the users choice argument but in enterprise apps it is sometimes necessary to have such control.
PS Try not to be such a patronizing git.

Comment: LOL. I wouldn't be a 'patronizing git' if you showed at least bit of interest while posting your question, because in this form it was very likely it would stay unanswered. You know, that's how we roll here on StackOverflow - people post *descriptive* questions and others provide *detailed* answers.

Next time write all this info in your initial question so we all know how to help.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried, but it looks like you might be able to do something by using the [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).  You're going to need to have the `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission set as well.

Comment: Nope, its not possible to catch or block incoming calls